# Why is my constructor called twice

Tags: java, multithreading, client

I am creating a multi threaded client server program.

There is a Client Login JPanel  which authenticates the user by sending the username and password to the server for checking and server will send back to client : "Yes" if its correct

```
if (UsernameandPasswordMatch.equals("Yes"))
  {
       String numofplayers = Utility.ReadFromServer();
       int numofplayer_int = Integer.parseInt(numofplayers);
       new GameTablePanel(numofplayer_int).start(numofplayer_int);

       //change to game table panel 
   }
```

This is the start method of the GameTablePanel class

```
void start(int numofplayer_int)
    {
        JLayeredPane lpane = new JLayeredPane();
        lpane.setBounds(0, 0, 1200, 750);

        JPanel background = new WallPaper();
        //background.setBounds(0, 0, 1200, 750);
        background.setOpaque(true);

    GameTablePanel panel = new GameTablePanel(numofplayer_int); //called 2nd time
        //panel.setBounds(100, 100, 400, 400);
        panel.setBounds(0,0,1200,750);
        panel.setOpaque(false);

        lpane.add(background, new Integer(0), 0);
        lpane.add(panel, new Integer(1), 0);

        Utility.ChangeJLPanel(lpane);

    }
```

Using the debugger, I realised that the Constructor is immediately called once i enter the start method and is called again when i reached the

> GameTablePanel panel = new GameTablePanel(numofplayer_int)

FYI: I am creating a new thread on the server side everytime a client connects to the server

**How do i call my constructor only ONCE instead of twice**

Comment: ...just don't call it again? Why does your method have another copy of the containing class? Should you just be adding all those things to `this` instead of `panel`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that you are explicitily calling it twice, once from here

```
new GameTablePanel(numofplayer_int).start(numofplayer_int);
```

and again from inside the start method of `GametablePanel`. Is that what you want? I am not familiar with what you are trying to do but since your start method already belongs to that panel you might as well do this:

```
void start(int numofplayer_int) {
        JLayeredPane lpane = new JLayeredPane();
        lpane.setBounds(0, 0, 1200, 750);

        JPanel background = new WallPaper();
        //background.setBounds(0, 0, 1200, 750);
        background.setOpaque(true);

        //this.setBounds(100, 100, 400, 400);
        this.setBounds(0,0,1200,750);
        this.setOpaque(false);

        lpane.add(background, new Integer(0), 0);
        lpane.add(this, new Integer(1), 0);

        Utility.ChangeJLPanel(lpane);
}
```

Comment: You can just drop `this.` entirely and write `setBounds(0,0,1200,750);` and `setOpaque(false);` without anything in front.

Comment: I always prefer the [object].[message] semantic, but yes, you can. In that case "this" will be implicit.

Comment: You prefer it?  I find it clutterish.  The only time I ever write `this.` is to set a field, either in a setter or in a constructor.  And yet, here we have three answers all advocating `this.`.  I find myself in a minority.

Comment: In this particular case it is useful to write it down just to point out the difference of calling `panel.setBounds(...)` and `this.setBounds(...)`, that is probably the cause of the tendency.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you were expecting, but you *are* instantiating two `GameTablePanel`'s. Its constructor will be called every time you use `new` in front of it. And each time you do that you will have a different reference to an instance of the class as a result (but you're throwing one away the first time). In your code, you instantiate a `GameTablePanel` the first time when the passwords match:

```
new GameTablePanel(numofplayer_int).start(numofplayer_int);
^
```

And then again inside `start()`:

```
GameTablePanel panel = new GameTablePanel(numofplayer_int);
                       ^
```

It seems like you're looking for a way to reference the instance of the class you created the first time from within `start()`. You can simply use the `this` keyword to do that:

```
void start() // don't need the parameter anymore
{
    JLayeredPane lpane = new JLayeredPane();
    lpane.setBounds(0, 0, 1200, 750);

    JPanel background = new WallPaper();
    //background.setBounds(0, 0, 1200, 750);
    background.setOpaque(true);

    // Update self
    //this.setBounds(100, 100, 400, 400);
    this.setBounds(0,0,1200,750);
    this.setOpaque(false);

    lpane.add(background, new Integer(0), 0);
    lpane.add(this, new Integer(1), 0);

    Utility.ChangeJLPanel(lpane);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the line:
`new GameTablePanel(numofplayer_int).start(numofplayer_int);`

To
`new GameTablePanel(numofplayer_int).start();`

It is not needed since you've initialized it with the argument in the constructor.

Inside of the start you already have an instance of the GameTablePanel, so instead of creating a new one just use "this":

```
    //panel.setBounds(100, 100, 400, 400);
    this.setBounds(0,0,1200,750);
    this.setOpaque(false);

    lpane.add(background, new Integer(0), 0);
    lpane.add(this, new Integer(1), 0);

    Utility.ChangeJLPanel(lpane);
```